# SElinux Permissive setting enable/disable black screen

Tags: 16.04, screen, selinux

I installed SELinux on Ubuntu 16.04 and changed the permissive setting to disabled. When I restart the computer, I just get a black screen upon startup. I have not enabled SELinux again.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a completely black screen, or is anything else present (such as a prompt, cursor, etc)?

Comment: [link](http://i.hizliresim.com/vXy5Q4.png)

later this just black screen

Answer (score 1):

When the black screen first appears type in your password ( YOU WON'T BE LOOKING AT ANYTHING ON THE SCREEN) and hit enter. it might be your graphics card keeping your screen dark while your operating system is still working and you just cannot see it until completly booted  :-)